# NativeScript: change background color and text of a Button belonging to a ListView

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

I need a 2-state toggle Button: at each tap, that changes its background color and its text label (color and text). Its implementation is simple and it works correctly when the button belongs to a simple page. 
Instead, when the button is put in each element of a simple list (20 elements) it does not change its background color, and only its label text changes, not its color.

Here some code details to check the problem:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView items="{{ items }}" itemTap="onItemTap">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="follow-button">
                <Button text="Undefined" tap="onTap"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

and in js side ('value' not binded to a button, is used here only to demonstrate tap problem on a single button of the list):

```
var value = 1;
exports.onTap = function (args) {
    view  = args.object;
    value = value === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    view.text            = value === 1 ? "button on" : "button off";
    view.backgroundColor = value === 1 ? "red"       : "white";
    view.color           = value === 1 ? "white"     : "red";
}
```

I see that removing or fixing the text then background changes correctly at each tap.

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you create the playground demo?

Comment: Here is the playground demo https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=Hms4zb&v=2 I've just checked that in Android is ok, problem arises with iOS.

Comment: I am having a similar/same problem.  I use declarative binding of a CSS class, setting an "isComparing" boolean var in the event handler and enabling the class like so: `[class.active]="item.isComparing"`

For me, it changes the background color (via the CSS class) once, then never changes it back.  I even added a converse CSS class inactive to reset the background to white and that still didn't work: `[class.inactive]="!item.isComparing"`

The CSS: 
`
button.compare.inactive {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  button.compare.active {
    background-color: $cd-orange; 
  }
`

Comment: Please check my solution below, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the fix described [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4489) *seems* works like a charm!

It is the only solution I found that leaves intact the app code without introduce tricks that break the philosophy behind using components.

Just put this:

```
Object.defineProperty(View.prototype, "isLayoutValid", {
    get: function () {
        return (this._privateFlags & PFLAG_LAYOUT_REQUIRED) !== PFLAG_LAYOUT_REQUIRED;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

in

`node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.ios.js`

And everything is magically fixed!